# Android Application ID

Tags: android, app-id

Can anyone say how to get an application id of market application installed in device. I want to get ID of particular installed application?

Answer (score 1):

```
    boolean installed = appInstalledOrNot(Your App Package as String);

    if(installed){
           ////////App is Installed
    }

        private boolean appInstalledOrNot(String uri) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                return true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                return false;
            }

        }
```